# Running spark application in local mode

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to start my Spark application in local mode using spark-submit. I am using Spark 2.0.2, Hadoop 2.6 & Scala 2.11.8 on Windows. The application runs fine from within my IDE (IntelliJ), and I can also start it on a cluster with actual, physical executors.

The command I'm running is

`spark-submit --class [MyClassName] --master local[*] target/[MyApp]-jar-with-dependencies.jar [Params]`

Spark starts up as usual, but then terminates with

`java.io.Exception: Failed to connect to /192.168.88.1:56370`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Check which port you are using: if on cluster: log in to master node and include:

```
--master spark://XXXX:7077
```

You can find it always in spark ui under port 8080

Also check your spark builder config if you have set master already as it takes priority when launching eg:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("myapp")
  .master("local[*]")
```

Comment: run local on local machine but spark://XXXX:7077 from master node

Comment: But I'm not running on a cluster, I want to run it in local mode on my machine. Surely I don't have to replace the "local[*]" then?

Comment: in that case place `val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")` in your code, and do not use --master in submit, but when you use --master in submit option ensure that you put `spark:xxx:7077` as master: simply copy from localhost:8080 web ui, and do not set master from spark builder in main method

Comment: I omitted the --master argument from the spark-submit call, and added .master("local[*]") from code, but I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: can you do it other way round? to see if the error persists?: copy master link from localhost:8080 and paste as --master in spark submit while deleting it form code, also can you run it from ide or zeppelin ?

Comment: Well, I can't pass something other than local as --master if I want to run it in local mode. I couldn't pass the port anyways, because in local mode it starts up the driver and assigns it to a random port. If I run it on the actual cluster, passing the correct master url with --master, it works. Running from the IDE, with setMaster("local[*]"), it works as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134833/discussion-between-karol-sudol-and-dnr).